# Matplotlib versions > 2.2.2 not available

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pip

For another piece of software, I need matplotlib >= 2.4. I can't seem to install this on my windows 10 machine.

I have used both pip, specifying and not specifying the version number, and conda, and both have installed matplotlib-2.2.2 or failed to complete.

When I run

```py
import matplotlib
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
```

the output is always

```py
matplotlib: 2.2.2
```

Comment: When trying to install matplotlib 2.4 you should get some feedback as to why that fails. One would need to know what it says to help further.

Comment: The latest 2.x release is 2.2.4.  3.1 exists but won’t work for python 2.x.

Comment: Ha, that explains it. Those micro and nano versions even confuse me.